# Determine if an angle is nearly upright

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I have a significant number of objects for which I have calculated their "tilt". I want to process those objects that are close to being upright (a tilt near 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees). I have the following brute-force code that works fine:

```
angle = Math.Abs(angle);
var tooTilted = (angle > 000 + maxTilt && angle < 090 - maxTilt)
             || (angle > 090 + maxTilt && angle < 180 - maxTilt)
             || (angle > 180 + maxTilt && angle < 270 - maxTilt)
             || (angle > 270 + maxTilt && angle < 360 - maxTilt);
```

I have this itch in the back of my head making me think there's a geometric or trigonometric trick I could be using to perform the same test more succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angle % 90.  Then you only need your first test case.  [% (mod)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) takes the remainder after being divided by 90.

```
angle = Math.Abs(angle) % 90;
var tooTilted = (angle > 000 + maxTilt && angle < 090 - maxTilt)
```